# PHP sanitizing location data

Tags: php, sanitization

I've got this html

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="Iraq">1</option>
    <option value="Texas">2</option>
    <option value="Paris">3</option>
    ...
    <option value="n">nnn</option>
</select>
```

There are a really hellish lot of options in this select element and I wouldn't really like to allow people to change the values of any options and I can't stop them from doing that, though, I am curious, is there an efficient PHP way to check if the value legit, for example, I could do this:

```
<?php
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    if(($country == "Iraq") && ($country == "Texas") && ($country == "Paris) ....($country == "n"))
{
    allow stuff;
}
?>
```

But that would require a really huge amount of if statements, isn't there another magical way to solve this problem?

Comment: Sidenote: Countries will never be `AND/&&`, but `OR/||`.

Comment: You should keep those option values somewhere in an array (or database) and echo them out while creating the form, and use the same array for filtering the input.

Comment: By the way, it looks like you have your values and texts the wrong way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, use `in_array`:

```
$countries = ['Iraq','Texas',...];
if(in_array($_POST['country'], $countries)) {
    // allow stuff
}
```

Build your `$countries` array once, and then use it to generate your `<select`> HTML code and to validate the submission. Bonus!

Side note: I need to visit the country of Texas. Didn't realize they seceded!

Comment: Wasn't thinking, just typed in randomly, stupid me :D I'll accept your A in a coulpe of minutes

Answer (score 0):

This is far from magic but one (somewhat efficient) way to check would be to use `in_array`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Once you have an array of your countries, you can also use it to generate the drop down.